# Civi plugin fails to install on fresh version of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

Server is Ubuntu 23.04
Php 8.1 using FPM

On a fresh install of Wordpress, and a fresh download of civi, as soon as I activate the plugin in Wordpress plugins, it errors out. Here are the details.

Any ideas?

```
Active theme: Twenty Twenty-Four (version 1.0)
Current plugin: CiviCRM (version 5.65.1)
PHP version 8.1.12-1ubuntu4.3



Error Details
=============
An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 22 of the file /home/lostswordfish/domains/civitest.lostswordfish.com/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/AbstractLogger.php. Error message: Declaration of Psr\Log\AbstractLogger::emergency($message, array $context = []) must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void
```