# Unable to install CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, installation

I am attempting to install a fresh copy of CiviCRM 5.70.1 on WordPress 6.4.3
I have been working with CiviCRM for years and I have never encountered this issue before.

After uploading and extracting the Civicrm zip file and activating it in Wordpress, I then attempt to click the CiviCRM Installer link and it does not direct to the install page as normal. Instead it install displays a critical error message as you can see in the screenshot below.

**The logs show :**

***An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 22 of the file /home/blank/domains/thesite.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/AbstractLogger.php.
Error message: Declaration of Psr\Log\AbstractLogger::emergency($message, array $context
= []) must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency(Stringable|string
$message, array $context = []): void***

I have tried using different themes, modifying the permissions, disabling all plugins and even installing it o different website. I got the same issue each time.

I hope someone can help me resolve this. The emailed instructions just contain the error message, but no instructions on how to resolve it.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I know you said you disabled all plugins but there must be another plugin that's including a newer version of `psr/log`, because that's what the conflict is. Search in all the plugins' vendor folders for a folder called psr and see if there's another copy of log in there.

Comment: Noting this is very similar to the problem reported here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/47580/225

Comment: We actually started over with a fresh install on a site with zero plugins and we still received this error.  Could psr/log conflict be from something other than a plugin?